# How do you set textfield tags so that return field will go to next field? This is inside tableview cells

Tags: swift, xcode

I have text fields in three different tableview cells

cell1- 1 textfield
cell2 - 2 textfields
cell3 - 3 textfields

Cells will display randomly depending on the product in the cell. There will be around 200 rows of cells with fields.

I want the keyboard return key to go to the next field when pressed. If all cells just had one field I could do this easily but because all cells are displayed randomly with 2 cells having multiple text fields I can't figure it out.

[image]

EX:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a model that determines when/where a text field is shown? If so, can you add your model to the question.

Comment: Ive added an example image. Products will be added and removed so the order will be changing a lot.

Comment: I don't think this is possible to do?